# What base does the author take when taking the log of both sides?

Tags: probability-distributions, logarithms, exponential-distribution, cumulative-distribution-functions

I am learning exponential distribution in ThinkStats2 by Allen Downey..
It says that "if you plot the complementary CDF of a dataset that you think is
exponential, you expect to see a function like:
$$
y\approx e^{-\lambda x}
$$
Then, taking the log of both sides yields:"
$$
\log y \approx -\lambda x 
$$

My question is what base does the author take when taking the log of both sides? I guess that the author takes log of base 10, but it does not explain why we get $-\lambda x$ on the right side of equation.
Could someone explain this?

Comment: There is $\text e$; thus, it is "natural" to consider [natural logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_logarithm)

Comment: When mathematicians write $\log(y)$ they are usually referring to the natural log (that is, the base $e$ logarithm) of $y$.

Comment: Some authors use $\ln(x)$ for the natural logarithm and $lg(x)$ for the logarithm to base $10$. But "$log(x)$" for the natural logarithm is very common.

Comment: Thank you so much ! I thought natural log is always referred as ln() form.

Comment: The fact that the log of $e^{-\lambda x}$ turns out to be $-\lambda x$ is a pretty good hint that the base is $e$, @Sherlock.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The author takes the natural logarithm on both sides (base $e=2.7182818\cdots $)

Answer (score 0):

In your case author takes base "$e$"

$y\approx e^{-\lambda x} \Leftrightarrow \log_{e} y \approx -\lambda x$

Generally we should guess outgoing from logarithm main property:
$$a=b^x \Leftrightarrow \log_{b} a =x$$
or
$$a=b^{log_{b} a}$$

Answer (score 0):

The author uses $\log$ base $e$, called the [natural log](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_logarithm), where $e$ is [Euler's number](https://courses.lumenlearning.com/boundless-algebra/chapter/the-real-number-e/).

$e\approx2.718281828459045$.

In general, mathematicians use $\log x$ to represent the natural $\log$ of $x$
Also, the base of the logarithm will normally be the same as the base of the exponential. This is because

for $A\gt0,\; A\neq1$:
$$y=A^x\iff\log_Ay=x$$
In your case, $A=e$, so the base of the $\log$ is $e$.