# Find the Rate Parameter Value of Exponential Distribution With Given Probability

Tags: probability, exponential-distribution

I am finding the value of rate parameter but unfortunately I am confused to get it. The  question is in below:

I am solving an exponential distribution question and I am confused with the given rate parameter. The exponential distribution question is in below:

**Suppose that the lifetime $X$  of a fuse (in 100 hour units) is exponentially distributed with $P(X>10)=0.8$. Find the rate parameter.**

As I understand for this question:

$$\begin{align} 
                  P(X>10) = 0.8\\
                  0.8 = e^{-\lambda 10}
\end{align}
$$

Here I am confused to substitute lambda aside to calculate it. May I know how can I substitute lambda aside to calculate lambda value? Or do I interpret correctly to find the rate parameter?

Comment: Take the logarithm of both sides to solve for $\lambda$

Comment: Hello @layabout thank you very much for your comments. With your comment, I found similar idea under this post https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3740923/what-base-does-the-author-take-when-taking-the-log-of-both-sides . Therefore if I understand it correctly for my case, the logarithm of both sides for $\lambda$ is $\log 0.8 \approx -\lambda 10 $  ?